# Can I conditionally control method calls at runtime with attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, aop

The [Conditional Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622(VS.71).aspx) in .NET allows you to disable the invocation of methods at compile time. I am looking for basically the same exact thing, but at run time. I feel like something like this should exist in AOP frameworks, but I don't know the name so I am having trouble figuring out if it is supported.

So as an example I'd like to do something like this

```
[RuntimeConditional("Bob")]
public static void M() {
   Console.WriteLine("Executed Class1.M");
}

//.....

//Determines if a method should execute.
public bool RuntimeConditional(string[] conditions) {
    bool shouldExecute = conditions[0] == "Bob";

    return shouldExecute;
}
```

So where ever in code there is a call to the **M** method, it would first call **RuntimeConditional** and pass in *Bob* to determine if **M** should be executed.

Comment: In your example, What kind of code would make M execute? What kind of code would make it not execute, and what would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: The RuntimeConditional Method would control if it would execute. Right now Bob is hardcoded, so it will always execute. The string Bob in the RuntimeConditional Method would be replaced with some code to pull from a config file/database field to see if the method should be called or not.

Comment: You could simply throw an exception in the OnEntry override of the Trace attribute. Not quite what you were looking for, but it will stop your method from executing.

Comment: I want to achieve the same behavior as the regular Conditional attribute. Throwing an exception is going would break that behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually use [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) to do what you want.

Here's a simple example you can use:

```
[Serializable]
public class RuntimeConditional : OnMethodInvocationAspect
{
    private string[] _conditions;

    public RuntimeConditional(params string[] conditions)
    {
        _conditions = conditions;
    }

    public override void OnInvocation(MethodInvocationEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_conditions[0] == "Bob") // do whatever check you want here
        {
            eventArgs.Proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

Or, since you're just looking at "before" the method executes, you can use the `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`:

```
[Serializable]
public class RuntimeConditional : OnMethodBoundaryAspect 
{
    private string[] _conditions;

    public RuntimeConditional(params string[] conditions)
    {
        _conditions = conditions;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_conditions[0] != "Bob")
        {
            eventArgs.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return; // return immediately without executing
        }
    }
}
```

If your methods have return values, you can deal with them too.  `eventArgs` has a `returnValue` property that is settable.

Comment: Cool.  Though I just realised i mucked up the logic - you want FlowBehaviour.Return if the condition is *not* met.

Comment: This is nice, but is it possible to do it with a simple attribute without relying on third party? I have a project where to get third party library approved is a long process. I was hoping for something simple and fast, where you can say if this variable is true execute the method else simply return.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be a very simple way of doing what you described:

```
public static void M() 
{
   if (RuntimeConditional("Bob"))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Executed Class1.M");
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah that isn't using attributes though.