# What is the correct design pattern to "turn off" an instance of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class with a bunch of methods and I want those methods to essentially no-op if a flag in a config file is turned off. . What would be the type of design pattern to follow? I've thought of hacky things like conditionally running methods (e.g. [Can I conditionally control method calls at runtime with attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242422/can-i-conditionally-control-method-calls-at-runtime-with-attributes)).

Comment: Define "correct". There are likely multiple ways to do it, and the right one for you depends on your particular circumstances and what's important to you.

Comment: This may be of interest to you for your application: [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is an interface in between, you could replace the implementation with a dummy in that case. Like

```
interface IFoo
    void DoBla()

class DummyFoo : IFoo
    void DoBla() {}

class RealFoo : IFoo
    void DoBla() {
        [some actual code]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple. No pattern and all over-thinking IMHO. If you don't want a method to perform anything if flag is off, you shouldn't call the method itself.

```
IF Config.Flag = OFF
    DoNothing();
ELSE
    CallMethod();
```

Vs.

```
CallMethod() {
    IF Config.Flag = OFF
        DoNothing();
    ELSE
        DoSomething();
}
```

Reason why I would vote on 1st one is because the reader of your code knows what's going on and significance of the config flag. In later case if they don't know about flag, they may expect something to happen and get confused when nothing happens.

Comment: I'd vote on the second, because, while less readable, is going to cause less code bloat, if there are lots of calls to these methods, and ensures that all calls to the method actually behave as desired, if unexpected.

Comment: You have a point too.

Comment: comments are important in this case. The class should be well documented to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively painless way to implement such functionality would be to use delegate invocation using the null-conditional operator.

Define your delegates for the given methods:

```
private Action ConditionalSomeMethod;
private Action<string> ConditionalSomeMethod2;

private void SomeMethod() { }
private void SomeMethod2(String arg) {Console.WriteLine(arg);}
```

Then assign the delegates based on your condition.

```
private void SetupConditionalMethods()
{
    bool runConditionals = true;
    if (runConditionals)
    {
        ConditionalSomeMethod = SomeMethod;
        ConditionalSomeMethod2 = SomeMethod2;
    }
    else
    {
        ConditionalSomeMethod = null;
        ConditionalSomeMethod2 = null;
    }
}
```

Sample usage using null-conditional operator.

```
private void DemoIt()
{
    ConditionalSomeMethod?.Invoke();
    ConditionalSomeMethod2?.Invoke("hello");
}
```

If the delegate is null, the method is not invoked.